# How Can I Execute Environment Variables in Shell Script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have 2 files.
One is list file named **envlist**.
Another one is shell script file named **test**.

In **envlist**(list file), there's the environment variable list as below ;

```
setup_top
CFG
```

those are already declared as the environment variable.

(So when I type **cd $setup_top** or **cd $CFG** in command, it works well)

And in **test**(shell script), there's the code as below ;

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=$(<$env/envlist)     # $env is another environment variable I declared.
for i in ${dir[*]}
do
     cd $i               # I think this line is a matter.
     echo "------------------"
     sleep 2
done
```

When I executed this shell script, I got the error as below;

```
./test: line 6: cd: setup_top: No such file or directory
----------------------------
./test: line 6: cd: CFG: No such file or directory
----------------------------
```

reading **envlist** file line by line seems to work well, but cd command seems not to work.

How can I fix the shell script code to work fine?

Comment: If `setup_top` and `CFG` are relative paths, you need to include a `cd ..` at the end of your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you need to transform `$i` into the name of the variable, then read `$varname`. If the shell would support this, you should write `cd $$i`. Unfortunately, this will not work, because `$$` gives the current PID.

As suggested by @Biffen, you should use shell variable substitution:

```sh
cd ${!i}
```

Previous answer, using dangerous `eval` instruction:

```sh
eval cd \$$i
```

Note: `eval` is a dangerous instruction. Use it only if you are sure of the content of your files (not files provided by untrusted users).

Comment: Thank Veyret for answering me. You gave me two answers. Unfortunatly I had same wrong answer after changing the line. Only two "------------" are the things I got from terminal.

Comment: when I tried Bourne-Again Shell Script, ASCII text executable, it failed. But When I tried Bourne-Again Shell Script, UTF-8 unicode text executable, it works!!! Thanks!!!!

Comment: @SatthewSeongHunMoon What else do you expect?! `cd` doesn’t print anything.

Comment: Nah What I wanted to say was When I execute that line, It shoild be moved to $setup_top or $CFG. But it didn't move at all

Comment: @SatthewSeongHunMoon How did you verify that? You can’t ‘see’ the working directory changing.